# Pieces doesn't stack after one loop on my connect4

Tags: python

I'm working on a connect4 and I have an issue on the `piece slide down` part. 
When I launch the game, the pieces stacked themself only once like that.

```
000000
000000
000000
000000
000000
PP0000
XX0000
```

But after that, it doesn't stack anymore. If the user chose to put a piece on the first or second row it won't stack the piece over the actual one. I tried to figure out where the issue was coming from but I don't see it and beeing new in python doesn't help a lot.

```py
board = []

for x in range(0, 7):
    board.append(["O"] * 6)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print(" ".join(row))

def user_one(board):
    status = 0
    clm = 0
    first_x = int(input("Enter a Row: "))
    for i in board:
        while i == "0":
            clm += 1
        if board[clm - 1][first_x - 1] == "P":
            board[clm - 2][first_x - 1] = "X"
        else:
            board[clm - 1][first_x - 1] = "X"
    status = 1
    print_board(board)

def user_two(board):
    status = 0
    clm = 0
    second_p = int(input("Enter a Row: "))
    for i in board:
        while i == "0":
            clm += 1
        if board[clm - 1][second_p - 1] == "X":
            board[clm - 2][second_p - 1] = "P"
        else:
            board[clm - 1][second_p - 1] = "P"
    status = 2
    print_board(board)

def launch_game(board):
    while True:
        user_one(board)
        user_two(board)

launch_game(board)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think overall was a bit of confusion between column and row. I took your code and modified it a little bit. So this should work:

```
board = []

for x in range(0, 7):
    board.append(["O"] * 6)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print(" ".join(row))

def user_one(board):
    clm = 0
    selected_column = int(input("Enter a column: "))

    for i in reversed(range(len(board))):
        if board[i][selected_column-1] == "O":
            board[i][selected_column-1] = "X"
            break

    print_board(board)

def user_two(board):
    clm = 0
    selected_column = int(input("Enter a column: "))
    for i in reversed(range(len(board))):
        if board[i][selected_column-1] == "O":
            board[i][selected_column-1] = "P"
            break
    print_board(board)

def launch_game(board):
    while True:
        user_one(board)
        user_two(board)

launch_game(board)
```

You can still improve on removing unused variables, names and refactoring the functions (so that you only have one for your `piece slide down`).

Comment: it works perfect thanks, could you explain me why you used the `reversed()` function please ?

Comment: Sure: `range(5)` creates [0,1,2,3,4] and `reversed(...)` reverses that list to [4,3,2,1,0]. The last printed lines from your board are the ones with the highest index in the list. Thats why we need to start with the higher indices and go back.